# Bitinstant order was processed, but is not showing in blockchain - did I screw up?

Tags: blockchain, buy-bitcoins, bitinstant

Did I do something wrong?  Here's the output from the order status page:

```
Quote ID    a086c30f-04a2-491c-b616-88655077ea68
Event ID    8db863ac-c880-45ae-b96e-ed8ece6e1021
Fees (inclusive)    3.99%%
Amount you paid $500.0 USD
Amount you will receive $480.05 USD
Destination exchange    Bitcoin Address
Destination account 1Jhbh2bezGY9GGPtkUdFixvtfrUpBHU55R

Timestamp   Event ID    Event type
Tue Apr 2 03:08:27 2013 8db863ac-c880-45ae-b96e-ed8ece6e1021    Quote for new transaction
Tue Apr 2 03:40:38 2013 44d23e52-d977-4e1c-825b-2dd9166a72d3    New Order
Tue Apr 2 03:41:49 2013 6bb94555-9e73-4d4f-a9bc-a5cc7e93492d    MTGox Connection Error
Tue Apr 2 03:51:50 2013 980e15b8-6c8a-45af-87b7-0fe9427bd818    Order executed - funds deposited at remote exchange
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it that this is the transaction you are waiting for: [922ce90177...](https://blockchain.info/tx/922ce9017732c967c217e4cce7ad9f34527778db2d506320481fdd3d05f0e8b3). As you can see it has been submitted to the network and will eventually show up in your client as well.